# TypeScript Generic function return type issue

Tags: typescript

I want to define the function return type via TypeScript Generics. So the `R` can be anything what I will define.

`... Promise<R | string>` is not solution for me.

### Error

Error:(29, 9) TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'R'.
'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'R', but 'R' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.

```
import { isString, } from '@redred/helpers';

interface P {
  as?: 'json' | 'text';
  body?: FormData | URLSearchParams | null | string;
  headers?: Array<Array<string>> | Headers | { [name: string]: string };
  method?: string;
  queries?: { [name: string]: string };
}

async function createRequest<R> (url: URL | string, { as, queries, ...parameters }: P): Promise<R> {
  if (isString(url)) {
    url = new URL(url);
  }

  if (queries) {
    for (const name in queries) {
      url.searchParams.set(name, queries[name]);
    }
  }

  const response = await fetch(url.toString(), parameters);

  if (response.ok) {
    switch (as) {
      case 'json':
        return response.json();
      case 'text':
        return response.text(); // <- Error
      default:
        return response.json();
    }
  }

  throw new Error('!');
}

export default createRequest;
```

Comment: How do you intend for this function to be used? Do you want someone to be able to call `createRequest<number>(/*some arguments*/)` and have your function return a promise that resolves to a number?

Comment: Did you try to use 'await fetch<P>(url.toStrin(), paramters)'

Comment: The error is because, if you define R as another thing that is not a string, this function could return a promise of string instead of a promise of R (if as=='text') so the function doesn't fulfill the definition.

Comment: @NicholasTower yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to represent this distinction from the caller's side... if the caller specifies `"text"` then the return type is definitely `Promise<string>` and the function is not generic in `R` anymore.

Aside: TypeScript naming conventions usually reserve single-character uppercase names for generic type parameters (especially `T`, `U`, `K`, and `P`), so I will expand your `P` to `Params`.  Also, the identifier `as` is problematic because it is a reserved word in TypeScript and might confuse the IDE or compiler; I will replace `as` with `az` in what follows.  Okay, so your interface is

```
interface Params {
  az?: "json" | "text";
  body?: FormData | URLSearchParams | null | string;
  headers?: Array<Array<string>> | Headers | { [name: string]: string };
  method?: string;
  queries?: { [name: string]: string };
}
```

Here are the overloads I'd use.  One non-generic call signature which only accepts an `az` of `"text"`, and the other is generic in `R` and only accepts an `az` of `"json"` or `undefined`/missing. The *implementation* signature can involve `R | string` or `any` or whatever you want, since it is invisible from the caller's side.

```
async function createRequest(
  url: URL | string,
  { az, queries, ...parameters }: Params & { az: "text" }
): Promise<string>;
async function createRequest<R>(
  url: URL | string,
  { az, queries, ...parameters }: Params & { az?: "json" }
): Promise<R>;
async function createRequest<R>(
  url: URL | string,
  { az, queries, ...parameters }: Params
): Promise<R | string> {
  if (isString(url)) {
    url = new URL(url);
  }

  if (queries) {
    for (const name in queries) {
      url.searchParams.set(name, queries[name]);
    }
  }

  const response = await fetch(url.toString(), parameters);

  if (response.ok) {
    switch (az) {
      case "json":
        return response.json();
      case "text":
        return response.text(); // <- okay now
      default:
        return response.json();
    }
  }

  throw new Error("!");
}
```

And here's how we'd use it to get text:

```
const promiseString = createRequest("str", { az: "text" }); // Promise<string>
```

And here's how we'd use it to get some other type (which requires that the caller specify `R` because it can't be inferred):

```
interface Dog {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  breed: string;
  fleas: boolean;
}

const promiseDog = createRequest<Dog>("dog", {}); // Promise<Dog>
```

And note that you can't ask for `"text"` if you've specified `R`:

```
const notGeneric = createRequest<Dog>("dog", {az: "text"}); // error!
//                                     -----> ~~
// "text" is not assignable to "json" or undefined
```

Okay, I hope this helps you.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApynAtgZ2QbwFgAoZZOALwH4AuZAIgCscB7Ee5AHwcgA8x6AbhJkARiwAmAT1rIAYiyhYAInDBwuyAKoAlADIBlCBgQALdJlyaQAVwA2dzTjBRQAc2Glkp4xOg5ZAEEoTCkAHmDQsOdXEDcAPnjNAAlff018ZABtEGwIOhj3AF0Cl3dkAF9PMiwIMFNJWUK46uQARxtoYAgAukycvNLYtxLkZrdKzwqSEj8EOwwUGBsQBDBgNmRgHAMyuIAKXjo4ECkASjpeLbxxzxI4HClV5GXV9c2EKGNIHQgOnrA+xEyBsUDsdF0eicezcABpgZlKLD2p1XD1kQA6LEABwweUgUDwFToFmweAAZARyBQ6PQ+AJKiQLmgoCwsNsINEYfFPA8nggXis1hsQMhPt8IL9-s4wjp4kCvKDwdp9NDhvCvIiKMj-micJicXjagSiSSjRSqZRZExWOxGcRmahWeycJy5bzHs9XsKPl81JK-p0ZXKFWQlRDVdxxhqyFqdajuvrkFiMbjLHV0sS0OamSTnRzZWr3EkiF5gDBkPttrthvslWczgRgWGwcgALzIEAQADuKr0dbBZ1a02IwPLld1icbpbIZBgikrCDYzk7eS2osnPWnzdnSoxrpM5nN+7q+1ytXjXR6A1qRSHO5HZBHwKXIBXXxw2OXKA7cG7cGAMAXjqMwBzsDEwBYGt3H2M5kTTfF-HvUcywrfYPy-N8IAxFgAGtty8MgcG7QCzErSgCNnWcEAeFAbTYegaB3KivjAUFRQw78MWYNhYNaKiaNdHgIH4RjmNnVj2OQTisIgkTASHZAAHolOQMIAFpkDwuApE7Fhu3Evx4HsMAmMIqjpLqKSZNdbjbT4h9gWfLx6lZXsu17ABREJFH2egAEJ6GQ5zXxXbF81daC4nbMU-R+QMAT8mJ6GRLVaXpDgKkUlSWTZAtxniGZiFAAl4CQZBlBYCYZ1XWohncVo4DcfJOxsLBRGgVpRC+CAJHqlpgRgOxjBwOhxBYYaTimIrQqA8K8tdSqJg7cV-SlIMwDCJb5XoCQqpSggssEZTVKdBbOW2mblyAkAWDAABxCAu1cAUVrigNpU27a-L2twDvwSh0vk+gjpO5BoFZKB-JIHKLLh+GEcR5B1JRlGkgAP3RmHVLpYHrj0oCHhwYA3FyURhuQSCGB4u0FxWIzQF6oqSCAA)

Comment: Your solution works like charm but I have another issue. Can you please help me? I'm using your solution for createRequest function, but It does not work in another place. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57800985/typescript-class-using-function-with-many-shapes-overloads-generics