# typescript class using function with many shapes (overloads) | generics

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[TYPESCRIPT playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=6&jsx=2#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-reiy6ukVq0DwmRMhM7RcO627eihrDSnAGEAVhK5UMmoyAu2oIMZMlqEfgW5HqiFHhGw8oTOy0G0RqiywYseEWtUcBpDwvTAagFCoPYuqTICkFUJA2A-GmRiWtG3FIdRDRwQ+loyXJyZUNgmA0VhKp2JAgIIWRvHaPZDlGtovS9lsXAVAgtEOdUkA2iRlncNZfZcAZgoOegPkHM0xxBV5WGheFoCRfJWkpXFwWgCi3SQpAaXpdlkxZTl0X+QVDlifySSLA4ZRgaBoAAKJYukloVAAhL+6pJB0XQ9KeZY3qcgLsKQATVFwayWjNc0LWsdJzqa+6DGszxoJN9IVJtRbbSgFTsvyoAhj8k1-u+5KFMUVCPZYABylz4IKiGBruvoHixO5wIKK5xm50w4k++AvvmJonX6JL0iI7LDckXBTN06C9DdS6YUQZSEGs3X428EJQoKNUsgUJOQqQKOaNoMx7agk2gCloRBH0T0AML0HJoSQDiQyTW62Nkv+ixZpOtCpNw-OPOwAQALLYOYmQGeLWFKSpmQOEmNAFltfr1U1pwoIWH6hnj6RrKTpBuhTNs026ArNTD86nZkinjjqBmDueyY4rg2AK+S90ay14B68mkC6YWlrq2Hlp0lbBMgU7lWyVFlO2870YibR3KyOHWFSZkdLfYDbors7Fu63AVAwGU8CmelpcZ1ZCm5MpqnHQuAvlpBRk-SZoAgKAOJqGoXU9YQrsOXXbEx2gnTx3dFZ0hTuciQ13nOeAVop558+R-X0exyvCfr6zM9b-FTXiS3lVcCihBWkfRpRWXRqR6toQ18BC9G7YGbnPSqYVCAkRWvNUISc3aGwPGsBevcPZuioGgheZtOi5xggkDUQA)

Exists something like `Overloads` for `class`? I created previous issue associated with createRequest.ts and the function should be without error. I want to define same generics for `class Data` like generics in `createRequest` function.

## Error

> Error:(31, 52) TS2345: Argument of type 'RequestParameters' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestParameters & { as?: "json" | undefined; }'.
>     Type 'RequestParameters' is not assignable to type '{ as?: "json" | undefined; }'.
>       Types of property 'as' are incompatible.
>         Type '"json" | "text" | undefined' is not assignable to type '"json" | undefined'.
>           Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json" | undefined'.

### Data.tsx

```js
import * as React from 'react';

import createRequest, { RequestParameters, } from '../../createRequest';

interface P<R> {
  children: (children: { createRequest: Data<R>['createRequest'] } & S<R>) => React.ReactNode;
  parameters: RequestParameters;
  url: Parameters<typeof createRequest>[0];
}

interface S<R> {
  error: Error | null;
  response: R | null;
}

class Data<R> extends React.Component<P<R>, S<R>> {
  async componentDidMount () {
    await this.createRequest();
  }

  state = { error: null, response: null, };

  createRequest = async (): Promise<void> => {
    this.setState(() => ({ error: null, response: null, }));

    try {
      const { parameters, url, } = this.props;

      const response = await createRequest<R>(url, parameters); // <-- Error

      this.onResponse(response);
    } catch (error) {
      this.onError(error);
    }
  };

  onError (error: Error): void {
    this.setState(() => ({ error, }));

    throw error;
  }

  onResponse (response: R): void {
    this.setState(() => ({ response, }));
  }

  render () {
    const { children, } = this.props;

    return children({ createRequest: this.createRequest, ...this.state, });
  }
}

export default Data;
```

### createRequest.ts

```js
import { isString, } from '@redred/helpers';

export interface RequestParameters {
  as?: 'json' | 'text';
  body?: FormData | URLSearchParams | null | string;
  headers?: Array<Array<string>> | Headers | { [name: string]: string };
  method?: string;
  queries?: { [name: string]: string };
}

async function createRequest (url: URL | string, parameters: RequestParameters & { as: 'text' }): Promise<string>;
async function createRequest<R> (url: URL | string, parameters: RequestParameters & { as?: 'json' }): Promise<R>;
async function createRequest<R> (url: URL | string, parameters: RequestParameters): Promise<R | string> {
  if (isString(url)) {
    url = new URL(url);
  }

  if (parameters.queries) {
    for (const name in parameters.queries) {
      url.searchParams.set(name, parameters.queries[name]);
    }
  }

  const response = await fetch(url.toString(), parameters);

  if (response.ok) {
    switch (parameters.as) {
      case 'json':
        return response.json();
      case 'text':
        return response.text();
      default:
        return response.json();
    }
  }

  throw new Error('!');
}

export default createRequest;
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `createRequest()` is overloaded but you are trying to use a single call for possibly both overloads, which doesn't work.  Overloads are almost like different functions from the caller's side... imagine you had `createRequestJson()` and `createRequestText()` and think about how you'd call those at once... it would need to look something like `someTest(parameters) ? createRequestJson<R>(url, parameters) : createRequestText(url, parameters)` where `someTest(parameters)` was a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) whose result would narrow `parameters` to the appropriate type.

The absolute simplest way to address this is to steamroll the compiler by [asserting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that `parameters` is of an acceptable type for the generic overload, such as the wildcard `any` type:

```
const response = await createRequest<R>(url, parameters as any); // no error
```

Any other fix is likely to require quite a lot of refactoring, because your `Data<R>` and `P<R>` types are swallowing the distinction between json requests and text requests.  So `createRequest()` cares about this distinction (which is why you got your error) but nothing else in the calling code does.  `Data<R>` is perfectly happy to represent a non-string `R` with properties including a `RequestParameters` whose `as` property is `"text"`.  If you're okay with that you might as well just push the assertion down into  `createRequest()` to get this non-overloaded function:

```
async function createRequest<R>(
  url: URL | string,
  parameters: RequestParameters
): Promise<R> {
  if (typeof url === "string") {
    url = new URL(url);
  }

  if (parameters.queries) {
    for (const name in parameters.queries) {
      url.searchParams.set(name, parameters.queries[name]);
    }
  }

  const response = await fetch(url.toString(), parameters);

  if (response.ok) {
    switch (parameters.as) {
      case "json":
        return response.json();
      case "text":
        return (response.text() as any) as R; // assertion
      default:
        return response.json();
    }
  }

  throw new Error("!");
}
```

and just deal with the fact that someone can call `createRequest<SomeRandomThing>(url, {as: "text"})`, maybe with a warning in the documentation.  Frankly I'd probably go this route, since the alternative is to split all your types and classes up into json and text flavors. It's not impossible, and if you care a lot about type safety you could do it.  But I doubt you care that much, since `createRequest<R>(url, {as: "json"})` is already not type-safe when the caller can pass in any random type for `R`.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=6&jsx=2#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-AQN4qCllyVxpPyOpQBAJYYwyGjQBRbpIUgfiBJE+jCEY0TmPE1j2NvU4H1ABwymrKtQAAUSxdJrQqABCQt1SSDouh6UAhjjYtH3AdhSACaouDWa1ARCsLQjWOljRefAzVYFA1meNA43pCpEtNfpUuOdl+VAAAyUAfjjIts3JQpiioWrLAAOUufBBRPYNpjWFLBm3Dq4EFLNwwI6YcTTfAMyNaoku6lASXpER2U85IuCmbp0F6CqrUC0AiDKQg1kcva3ghKFBSYj8uuOyFSCWzRtBmDLUAC3jQiCPo6oAYXod9QkgHF-KtD1NrJbatR1WhUm4X7HnYAIAFlsHMTIpP7RZv1-TIHGjGgprygMzPvJJFhQJLyzmHanP2ytro9c6YzWE7SA9AUicmk1kvywYybB9AUzDPzI2jWNcGwWHyWq7bFix3cY0gcCkutKSJetOldvSBmaZEt9jI1qFmZDeCsO5WRJYHJ9MjpdrZzgD0s2ZsnpaoGAyngBo1PNrWxO5n8-1yjmAzjICYPbOCFKUnE1DUBzKdZo3gplyZ5c6RWqptOk6aPfkDY44quNw8AUzVwhiLj7HZaT-AU-LNOKb2-Wbywu81VZ8KUUIPnTY9hLgtC8L7YrR3newV3Y704Tot70IVbZ6bObSqz45x9mZsgD0qHXx2Sc6fXGwSDUgA)